# Chrome Extension Timed Redirection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, timed

What I'm trying to achieve is make a chrome extension run in the background, and every minute it'll redirect to google.com and then a minute later redirect to stackoverflow.com and so on continuously until the icon is clicked by the wrench icon where most of the extensions are.

However I only know on how to redirect a page using
**window.location.replace("http://google.com");**

I'm still learning on how to develop chrome extensions, and just making some simple stuff for a learning process. I started learning from [this](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) tutorial, and tried a couple things out, and now I wanna figure out how to get something like this to work with it running in the background.

Comment: Which tab or page are you trying to redirect?

Comment: No page in particular, just a learning process. I grabbed a random url (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166121/drupal-android-app-login-persistence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just write a content script that you would inject, but it's easy enough that I just stored it in a variable. I would recommend looking at the [chrome.tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) API, as Google does a very good job of documenting their API for developers.

In your background page:

```
var REDIRECTION_SCRIPT_A = "window.location.href='http://www.google.com'";
var REDIRECTION_SCRIPT_B = "window.location.href='http://bit.ly/m2TXqC'";
var toGoogle = true;
var intervalId;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});

// Execute redirection script on current page
// Note that you can select any tab based on its ID by replacing
// null below
function annoyUser() {
  console.log("test");
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:
    (toGoogle ? REDIRECTION_SCRIPT_A : REDIRECTION_SCRIPT_B) });
  toGoogle = !toGoogle;
}

// Do once a minute ad infinitum
intervalId = setInterval(annoyUser, 5000);
```

In your manifest.json:

```
{
  ...
  "permissions": ["http://*/*", "tabs"],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks! They'll be more questions in the future regarding chrome extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Alternate solution (I am leaving url selection part out).

background.html:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "http://google.com"});
    });
}, 60000);

//stop
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```